# Multiple JoinColumns in Symfony2 using Doctrine annotations?

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, annotations

Here is the problem:

Class `Routing` with attributes `objectId` and `objectType`. `objectId` is an int, and `objectType` is a string. The reason for this was to allow the same table to hold data for different kind of routings. For instance for the routing of `Products`, `Department` and `Brand`. So, the combination of the `objectType` and the `objectId` is my JoinColumn.

How do I create such a bidirectional relationship with Doctrine2? I looked at inherited relationships, but none of the concepts seemed to be what I'm looking for.

I could create some views in the database and just have a couple of different Routing entities, but this does not seem the best route.

Here are my entities `Department`, `Product` and `Brand`.

`../Entity/Department.php`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="departments")
 */
class Department implements DescribableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
...
```

`../Entity/Product.php`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Product implements DescribableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_code", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $productCode = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
...
```

`../Entity/Brand.php`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="brands")
 */
class Brand
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $status = 'a';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
...
```

Each product, brand and department has its own URL that is held in the routing table set by the `object_type` and `object_id` where the `object_type` is simply `department`, `product` or `brand` and the `object_id` is the unique id of the corresponding product, brand or department.

`../Entity/Routing.php`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="routing")
 */
class Routing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;    

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_id", type="integer", length=11)
     */
    private $objectId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_type", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $objectType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="text")
     */
    private $url;
...
```

What I am really struggling with is how do I setup the relationship, so the departments, products and brands can access their URL from the single routing entity.

I have tried adding the relationships to the `$objectId`, but it doesn't seem to like that. Is it possible to set this up like this?

What I am basically trying to achieve is to get the data object and have the ability to get the URL of an object, for example:

```
$departments = $em->getRepository("AdamStaceySiteBundle:Department")->findAll();
foreach ($departments as $department)
{
   echo '<a href="'.$department->getUrl().'">'.$department->getMenuTitle().'</a>;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide the related code?

Comment: Am I alone who doesn't get the question?

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov That's why I asked for code :)

Comment: Sorry, will just add some code for you :-)

Comment: Updated with more content...

Comment: Please simplify your question. I got to abstract it to http://yuml.me/20136497.png , but it's been a huge mess just to understand how things are linked together. There's a load of annotations and useless fields that are completely unrelated with the question. Remove them first.

Comment: @Ocraminus, sorry I was asked to provide more detail. I will try and simplify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After further researching I found a man (Dirk Olbertz) in the know who had the same problem.

Information can be found at: [Google Groups: Multiple JoinColumns?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/HU_5h_Adq_g/I9ln4NZfsM8J)

I have now implemented this and I will explain how I did it incase it might help anyone else.

The answer to my problem was the use of single table inheritance.

The first thing I needed to do was update the `routing` entity to use single table inheritance:

`../Entity/Routing.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="object_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"product" = "ProductRouting", "department" = "DepartmentRouting", "brand" = "BrandRouting"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="routing")
 */
class Routing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
...
```

The `DiscriminatorColumn` allowed me to specify what column would be used to link, which in this case was the `object_type` field.

The `DiscriminatorMap` allowed me to specify what `object_type` will link with what entities.

These entities then had to be created that extended the `Routing` entity.

`../Entity/ProductRouting.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductRouting extends Routing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;
...
```

`../Entity/DepartmentRouting.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class DepartmentRouting extends Routing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Department")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $department;
...
```

`../Entity/BrandRouting.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BrandRouting extends Routing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $brand;
...
```

Then in each of the `Product`, `Department` and `Brand` entities I needed to add the new `$routings`.

`../Entity/Product.php`

```
...
class Product
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductRouting", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $routings;
...
```

`../Entity/Department.php`

```
...
class Department
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DepartmentRouting", mappedBy="department", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $routings;
...
```

`../Entity/Brand.php`

```
...
class Brand
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BrandRouting", mappedBy="brand", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $routings;
...
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: nice solution, but it seems to me or doctrine migrations will try to create foreign keys on object_id to different tables (Product, Department, Brand) and will be fail?