# symfony entity OneToOne error when updating schema

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

When I try to find `Miejsce` entity by ID :

```
$m= $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MiejsceObiektyBundle:Miejsce')
            ->find($id);
```

I get this error  :

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 286
>       500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Idea and real connection is

```
where subdomain.rid=miejsce.id and subdomain.ridType=1
```

subdomain work for many entities - so i dont want have doctrine var from subdomain to miejsce.

```
ridType=1 = miejsce
ridType=2 = product
ridType=3 = other
```

i can add condition subdomain.ridType=1 in repository - but there is problem to setup connection subdomain.rid=miejsce.id because miejsce dont have id reference for subdomain - its not need subdomain have it but not only for miejsce.... :)

what is wrong in this idea ? it is possible to use in doctrine ?

`Miejsce` entity :

```
  /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

 /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\DomainBundle\Entity\Subdomains")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="rid")
     * @var Subdomains
     */
    protected $subdomain;
```

`Subdomain` entity :

```
class Subdomains
{



    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $rid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $ridType;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `Miejsce` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Subdomains", mappedBy="miejsce")
 */
private $subdomain;
```

in `Subdomains` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce", inversedBy="subdomain")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $miejsce;
```

also rename `Subdomains` to `Subdomain` - entity names should be singular

Comment: This is something like i want but - not exactly. subdomain entity have many connections - miejsce and other entities so adding miejsce to subdomain is complicated :) so mayby is not possible to setup this idea

Comment: Its OneToOne relation, so Miejsce has Subdomain and Subdomain has Miejsce - there need to be corresponding variables for this in both entities.
Notice that $miejsce will be fetched only if you call getMiejsce() (if you will create that method). It will not hurt performance if you will not use it. Also there is no need for subdomain_id in Miejsce

Comment: maybe in doctrine exists other type relation to i can use in this situation ? to i dont must add additional not required by system but required by docrine duplicated keys ?

Comment: Maybe you need single table inheritance. Your DiscriminatorColumn would be `ridType`: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344426/multiple-joincolumns-in-symfony2-using-doctrine-annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344426/multiple-joincolumns-in-symfony2-using-doctrine-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subdomain_id", referencedColumnName="rid")
```

Comment: add new column subdomain_id ? in miejsce is no row subdomain_id connection is miejsce.id = subdomain.rid

Comment: take a look :http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing                  No need that field, it will be used for reference column. and after update schema it will generate a column in ur table.

Comment: but this is not selftoself reference

Comment: is possible to have reference like i have - miejsce.id = subdomain.rid  ? when i add @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subdomain_id", referencedColumnName="rid") docrine add key subdomain_id to miejsce

Comment: referencedColumnName  should be id

Comment: referenced is in subdomain so it reference column is rid. database idea exist - miejsce.id = subdomain.rid. miejsce have many columns i dont want add next if subdomain have it. Is possible ?