# Creating a one to many polymorphic relationship with doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let me start by outlining the scenario. I have a Note object that can be assigned to many different objects

- A **Book** can have one or more**Note**s.
- An **Image** can have one or more **Note**s.
- A **Address** can have one or more **Note**s.

What I envision the database to look like:

**book**

```
id | title           | pages
1  | harry potter    | 200
2  | game of thrones | 500
```

**image**

```
id | full      | thumb
2  | image.jpg | image-thumb.jpg
```

**address**

```
id | street      | city
1  | 123 street  | denver
2  | central ave | tampa
```

**note**

```
id | object_id | object_type | content      | date
1  | 1         | image       | "lovely pic" | 2015-02-10
2  | 1         | image       | "red tint"   | 2015-02-30
3  | 1         | address     | "invalid"    | 2015-01-05
4  | 2         | book        | "boobies"    | 2014-09-06
5  | 1         | book        | "prettygood" | 2016-05-05
```

The question is, how do I model this inside of Doctrine. Everything I have read about talks about single table inheritance without a one to many relationship.

To note (no pun intended ;), you may notice that note never needs unique attributes based on the object its related to.

Ideally I can do `$address->getNotes()` which would return the same type of Note object that `$image->getNotes()` would return.

At the very minimum the problem I am trying to solve is to avoid having three different tables: image_notes, book_notes and address_notes.

Comment: Naturally doctrine supports one-to-many relationships. Otherwise it would't be that popular :)  Read the symfony+doctrine documentation: it is written well, the doctrine documentation is a little more technical. Maybe you should create tables like 'imagenotes', 'addressnotes' and 'booknotes'.

Comment: I would like to avoid creating ImageNotes, AddressNotes and BookNotes tables.  They hold the exact same type of data (the attributes are the same)

Comment: Why are you `avoiding having three different tables: image_notes, book_notes and address_notes`? Is there any relation between these tables data. By keeping 3 separate tables, you will achieve good performance. Also can extend functionality in specific note.

Comment: Primarily because of redundancy.  The tables will hold the exact same information.

Comment: Does note need to be aware of his parent? I see you have an object_id column. This column can only point to one type of entity. If note does not need to be aware of its parent (drop this column) I will post a solution...

Comment: @Roeland, in third normal form they are not holding exaclty the same information, they just happen to have the same number and types of columns. This is one of the problems with ORMs, people stop modellig the database properly. Can the same note be moved from an image to an address, or be applied to both a book and an image? No, therefore they are not the same entity. Just create 3 tables for the 3 distinct entities. More tables is NOT a problem, undue complexity in your application is.

Comment: were you able to find a working solution?  If so, do you have code you can post?

Answer (score 5):

This question introduces unneccessary complexity into the application. Just because the notes have the same structure does not mean that they are the same entity. When modelling the database in 3NF, they are not the same entity because a note can not be moved from a Book to an Address. In your description there is a definitive parent-child relation between book and book_note, etc so model it as such.

More tables is not a problem for the database but unneccessary code complexity is, as this question demonstrates. It is just being clever for clevers sake. This is the trouble with ORMs, people stop doing full normalization and don't model the database correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I wouldn't use a superclass here. Think there's more of a case for an *interface* that would be implemented by `Book`, `Image` and `Address`:

```
interface iNotable
{
    public function getNotes();
}
```

Here's Book as an example:

```
class Book implements iNotable {
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Note", mappedBy="book")
     **/
    protected $notes;

    // ...        

    public function getNotes()
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }
}
```

`Note` then needs `@ManyToOne` relationships going the other way, only one of which will apply for each entity instance:

```
class Note {
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="notes")
     * @JoinColumn
     **/
    protected $book;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="notes")
     * @JoinColumn
     **/
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="notes")
     * @JoinColumn
     **/
    protected $address;

    // ...
}
```

If you don't like the multiple references to each notable class here you *could* use inheritance and have something like an `AbstractNotable` superclass using single table inheritance. Although this might seem tidier now, the reason I wouldn't recommend it is as your data model grows you may need to introduce similar patterns that could eventually make the inheritance tree become unmanageable.

**EDIT:** It would also be useful to have `Note` validator to ensure data integrity by checking that exactly one of `$book`, `$image` or `$address` is set for each instance. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @PrePersist @PreUpdate
 */
public function validate()
{
    $refCount = is_null($book) ? 0 : 1;
    $refCount += is_null($image) ? 0 : 1;
    $refCount += is_null($address) ? 0 : 1;

    if ($refCount != 1) {
        throw new ValidateException("Note references are not set correctly");
    }
}
```

Comment: how does the query know which `object_type` to look for if you have not specified it in any of the `@JoinColumn` annotations?

Comment: Hi, have you an example of AbstractNotable superclass please ?

Answer (score 2):

As you cant have several foreign keys on one column, you have 2 solutuons:

1. either make one sided `one2many` relations between Book/Image/Address and Note, so it would create a join table for each relation like book_note, image_note etc. holding the id pairs book.id-note.id etc. (I mean one2many instead of many2many because there usually is no point for a note to know which book or image or address it belongs to)

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

2. or make multiple entities `BookNote`,`ImageNote`,`AddressNote` related to a book/image/address and a note and other data if for example one type of a note has some other data in it.
3. you can use single table inheritance as described in accepted answer to this question, but it is a solution similar to one proposed by Steven, which makes you hold additional data in the discriminator column.

[Multiple JoinColumns in Symfony2 using Doctrine annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344426/multiple-joincolumns-in-symfony2-using-doctrine-annotations)

Doctrine documentation also mentions a performance hit in certain situations.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact

Solution given by Steve Chambers solves a problem but you force the note table to hold unnecessary data(empty id columns for other objects)

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is by using a unidirectional One-To-Many with a join table. [In doctrine this is done with a unidirectional Many-To-Many with a unique constraint on the join column](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table).

The disadvantage of this solution is that it is unidirectional meaning that your note is not aware of the owning side of the relationship. But at first glance it looks like this should not be a problem in  your case.
You will lose the `object_id` and `object_type` column in the note table.

In full code this  would look like this:

A `NotesTrait` with setters and getters for notes to prevent code duplication:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection; 

/**
 * @property Collection $notes
 */
trait NotesTrait
{
    /**
     * Add note.
     *
     * @param Note $note
     * @return self
     */
    public function addNote(Note $note)
    {
        $this->notes[] = $note;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add notes.
     *
     * @param Collection $notes
     * @return self
     */
    public function addNotes(Collection $notes)
    {
        foreach ($notes as $note) {
            $this->addNote($note);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove note.
     *
     * @param Note $note
     */
    public function removeNote(Note $note)
    {
        $this->notes->removeElement($note);
    }

    /**
     * Remove notes.
     *
     * @param Collection $notes
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeNotes(Collection $notes)
    {
        foreach ($notes as $note) {
            $this->removeNote($note);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get notes.
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getNotes()
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }
}
```

Your `Book` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Book
{
    use NotesTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Note")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="book_notes",
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="note_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Your `Address` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Address
{
    use NotesTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Note")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="address_notes",
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="note_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Your `Image` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Image
{
    use NotesTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Note")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="image_notes",
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="note_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I add another answer after reading your question once more and realizing that you stated *"I want to avoid adding another join table"*.

Make a `Note` base entity and extend this class in 3 different note entities for example: `BookNote`, `AddressNote` and `ImageNote`. In my solution the note table would look like this:

```
id | address_id | book_id | image_id | object_type | content      | date
1  | null       | null    | 1        | image       | "lovely pic" | 2015-02-10
2  | null       | null    | 1        | image       | "red tint"   | 2015-02-30
3  | 1          | null    | null     | address     | "invalid"    | 2015-01-05
4  | null       | 2       | null     | book        | "boobies"    | 2014-09-06
5  | null       | 1       | null     | book        | "prettygood" | 2016-05-05
```

You cannot use one common column `object_id` because of the foreign key constraints.

A `NotesTrait` with setters and getters for notes to prevent code duplication:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection; 

/**
 * @property Collection $notes
 */
trait NotesTrait
{
    /**
     * Add note.
     *
     * @param Note $note
     * @return self
     */
    public function addNote(Note $note)
    {
        $this->notes[] = $note;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add notes.
     *
     * @param Collection $notes
     * @return self
     */
    public function addNotes(Collection $notes)
    {
        foreach ($notes as $note) {
            $this->addNote($note);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove note.
     *
     * @param Note $note
     */
    public function removeNote(Note $note)
    {
        $this->notes->removeElement($note);
    }

    /**
     * Remove notes.
     *
     * @param Collection $notes
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeNotes(Collection $notes)
    {
        foreach ($notes as $note) {
            $this->removeNote($note);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get notes.
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getNotes()
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }
}
```

Your `Note` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="object_type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"note"="Note", "book"="BookNote", "image"="ImageNote", "address"="AddressNote"})
 */
class Note
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $content

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    protected $date
}
```

Your `BookNote` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class BookNote extends Note
{
    /** MANY-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
     * @var Book
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Book", inversedBy="notes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */    
    protected $book;
}
```

Your `AddressNote` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class AddressNote extends Note
{
    /** MANY-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
     * @var Address
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Address", inversedBy="notes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */    
    protected $address;
}
```

Your `ImageNote` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class ImageNote extends Note
{
    /** MANY-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
     * @var Image
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Image", inversedBy="notes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */    
    protected $image;
}
```

Your `Book` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Book
{
    use NotesTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** ONE-TO-MANY BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\BookNote", mappedBy="book")
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Your `Address` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Address
{
    use NotesTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** ONE-TO-MANY BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\AddressNote", mappedBy="address")
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Your `Image` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Image
{
    use NotesTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** ONE-TO-MANY BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ImageNote", mappedBy="image")
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works generally, but the entity id is not saved

Comment: @Matanya, How can the id not be saved? The `id` is the identifier column, so if something is saved, the `id` certainly is saved too... Can you elaborate on your problem. Or maybe post a new question?

Comment: I meant the *foreign* id. I assumed doctrine will auto-assign it once you add it to the owning entity (in my case broker_id when you add addresses to Broker entity). Apparently you need to explicitly call ```$address->setBroker($broker)```

Comment: @Matanya Yes, doctrine will only take care of the owning side of your relations. It is very important to take properly care of the inverse side yourself. Read for more information [this part of the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts)