# Multiple OneToMany relations to one Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Once upon a time in the dark abyss somewere deep in the lands of Symfony there was a frustrated programmer. He tried and tried but somehow the evil doctrine striked again and again. Also the villains `Joins`, `Associative tables` and `One-to-Many/Many-to-One` were giving him a hard time. Then, on a late afternoon `StackOverflow` and it's community came to the rescue.

Enough fairytales. My problem is that I have three tables that should all refer to the same table to get attachments.

```
- Mail
- Order
- Ticket
```

Each of these three entities can have attachments. So I made an Attachment entity.

Now, my database contains the following

```
Table: mails
- id
- from
- to
- message

Table attachments
- id
- name
- path

Table: orders
- id
- ...

Table: tickets
- id
- name
- description
- ...

Table attachment_associations
- id
- type
- parent_id
- attachment_id
```

What I wold like to do is to be able to map orders, tickets and mails to the same attachments table.

However, i'm stuck on how to do this in doctrine.

#### Update

I tried using the following method. This does seem to get the record I am looking for. But I don't know how to automatically create, update or delete the record in the associative table (join table) using this method.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\...\...\Entity\Attachment")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="attachment_associations",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={
 *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachmentId", referencedColumnName="id")
 *     }
 * )
 */
protected $attachments;
```

#### Another update

If I delete a Mail, Order or Ticket, will all corresponding attachments be deleted as well?

Comment: This is a good place to start http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Just create three association mappings - they can certainly be `null` for two columns while the third column is set to the entity the attachment belongs to.

Comment: Have you thought about implementing a mapped super class which manages the association. And have mails, orders and tickets extends from that? There are performance implications to this, but it could be one way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Yoshi I'm quite new to this whole scene. Could you elaborate?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027651/creating-a-one-to-many-polymorphic-relationship-with-doctrine/33172677#33172677) where you can find lot's of good and bad examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this very easily is to implement a [mapped super class](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) with [class table inheritance](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) which your other entities extend from.

Though there are [performance implications](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#id4) which you have to judge for your specific project.

Here's a simple example:

---

**The mapped super class**

```
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 */
abstract class SuperClass
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Attachment[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attachment", mappedBy="parents")
     */
    protected $attachments = [];

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // put setters/getters for $attachments here
}
```

**and the attachment** manage the association.

```
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Attachment
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var SuperClass
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SuperClass", inversedBy="attachments")
     */
    private $parents;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->parents = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**the entity** simply extends the super class

```
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Ticket extends SuperClass
{
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ManyToOne be a OneToMany instead? One mail can have many attachments.

Comment: Yeah that could be wrong. Didn't you want to have multiple attachments per entity, while each attachment can be assigned to multiple entities? If so, then a m-n should be the right type. I'll update the answer.

Comment: But anyway, using this as a starting point, you can very easily change the association without any impact on the extending entities.

Comment: @Wilt That's not correct. All entities will have their own tables. See https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Comment: @Yoshi, I will rephrase. They will have one common table with `id`, meaning for each query you will have to also search the common table and this table holds all 3 types of entities `Mail`, `Order` and `Ticket` which is bad for performance. Additionally you need lot's of joins every time you resolve your entities. All this for a simple attachment...!? Not a good idea IMHO

Comment: @Wilt This might be, though I explicitly pointed this out with the link to the official doc: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#id4 Provided that the joins are no problem, using [`INSTANCE OF`](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#query-the-type) inside the dql will help manage selection very easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can have all attachments in one table by using a unidirectional One-To-Many with a join table. [In doctrine this is done with a unidirectional Many-To-Many with a unique constraint on the join column](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table). It would mean one table with attachments but different join tables to connect to each parent.

The disadvantage of this solution is that it is unidirectional meaning that your attachment is not aware of the owning side of the relationship.

In full code this  would look like this:

A `AttachmentsTrait` with setters and getters for attachments to prevent code duplication:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection; 

/**
 * @property Collection $attachments
 */
trait AttachmentTrait
{
    /**
     * Add attachment.
     *
     * @param Attachment $attachment
     * @return self
     */
    public function addAttachment(Attachment $attachment)
    {
        $this->attachments[] = $attachment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add attachments.
     *
     * @param Collection $attachments
     * @return self
     */
    public function addAttachments(Collection $attachments)
    {
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            $this->addAttachment($attachment);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove attachment.
     *
     * @param Attachment $attachments
     */
    public function removeAttachment(Attachment $attachment)
    {
        $this->attachments->removeElement($attachment);
    }

    /**
     * Remove attachments.
     *
     * @param Collection $attachments
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeAttachments(Collection $attachments)
    {
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            $this->removeAttachment($attachment);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get attachments.
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getAttachments()
    {
        return $this->attachments;
    }
}
```

Your `Mail` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Mail
{
    use AttachmentsTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attachment")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="mail_attachments",
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachment_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mail_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    $attachments;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Your `Order` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Order
{
    use AttachmentsTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attachment")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="order_attachment",
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachment_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    $attachments;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Your `Ticket` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;    

class Ticket
{
    use AttachmentsTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attachment")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ticket_attachment",
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachment_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    $attachments;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attachments= new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

If you really want the `Attachment` to be aware of the other side you could add an additional entity in between to manage this. It would mean making the join tables themselves to entities for example: `MailAttachment`, `TicketAttachment` and `OrderAttachment`.

Comment: Won't this require 4 different tables? `mail_attachments`, `order_attachments` and `ticket_attachments`

Comment: @peter. Yes, you will have three join tables and one attachment table with all your attachments. They are in the association definitions.

Comment: @Peter You cannot do what you want with one table with a `partent_id` because of foreign key constraints. `parent_id` can only point (be a constraint) to one entity, not to three different ids `mail_id`, `order_id` and `ticket_id` at the same time.

Comment: @Peter You can do this with one base entity with a shared identifier `id` so you can point to this field with `parent_id` but I would definitely not recommend this. Mail, Ticket and Order should be in different tables, not in one common table.

Comment: Do I need an attachment entity as well?

Comment: @Peter When? With what solution? I thought you accepted Yoshi his answer. Do you mean with his solution or my solution or my alternative in **EDIT**?